# SQLiteException: no such column:

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the code for creating tables for the first time....

```
private void createTables(){

    SQLite ioclData=this.openOrCreateDatabase(Global.DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    ioclData.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS houses(name TEXT,location TEXT,category TEXT,city TEXT,phone TEXT);");
    try{
        c = ioclData.rawQuery("select * from houses where name="+"Darjeeling", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name","Darjeeling");
        cv.put("location", "ABCD");
        cv.put("category", "asdqwed");
        cv.put("city", "dqwedcx");
        cv.put("phone", "qdxcc");
        ioclData.insert("houses", null, cv);
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to access data....

private void showDetails(){

```
    c = ioclData.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM houses WHERE name="+home_selc, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    location.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location")));
    category.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category")));
    city.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("city")));
    phone.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone")));
}
```

The accessing data part is giving me this logcat error.....

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Darjeeling (code 1): , while compiling: select * from houses where name=Darjeeling

Comment: "select * from houses where name="+"Darjeeling;"

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Darjeeling (code 1): , while compiling: select * from houses where name=Darjeeling
```

the query is compiling Darjeeling as a column we need to put single quotes ('Darjeeling'), so that the compiled understood as an expression and not as a column, as if doing things like, join between tables.

```
c = ioclData.rawQuery("select * from houses where name="+"'Darjeeling'", null);
```

Comment: Can you please explain how your answer solves the problem so that this answer is helpful for future visitors?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I edited my answer according to what I believe is the cause of the problem, because I've had problems in the past as well :) !